# How to Merge 2 Kinect Application of 1.8 Sdk's?

Tags: background, combinations, kinect-sdk, skeleton-code

I am struggling from last 3 days to combine 2 application of kinect i.e. one is Background Removal and another one is Skeleton detection.

In my application i want to make skeleton detection and background removal together.

So if any one know how to do it please reply as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Means I just want to detect the Skeleton Joints in Background Removal Application

Please Reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BackgroundRemovalBasics-WPF project, go to the file named MainWindow.xaml.cs, and inside function 'SensorAllFramesReady' is the code you are searching for:

```
skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletons);
```

Following this line, you can get the skeleton you need and manipulate it.